# Selectively permitting mass assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm writing an application and using the authorization/authentication method from the Rails Tutorial as my basis. I want admin users to be able to change the admin status of other users while preventing non-admin users from doing the same. Is the following solution safe to implement? Is there a more elegant solution?

Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
...
  def user_params
    if current_user.admin?
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation, :admin)
    else
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end
  end
end
```

Helper:

```
module SessionsHelper

 def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    remember_token = User.digest(cookies[:remember_token])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using something like **[pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit#strong-parameters)**

#### app/policies/user_policy.rb

```
class UserPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def permitted_attributes
    attrs = [ :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation ]

    attrs << :admin if user.admin?

    attrs
  end
end
```

#### app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  # ...

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(*policy(@user || User).permitted_attributes)
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion; I'll keep this in mind if the authorization levels become more complex.